# Google App Engine Local Environment Error: "cannot import name webapp"

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've built a GAE site on a Windows machine and I want to work on it from my MacBook.  I have the code in SVN remotely and I installed the Mac version of GAE which comes with this launcher program.  When I configured my application in the launcher and fire the application up, I get the following error:

```
22 from datetime import timedelta
23
24 from google.appengine.ext import webapp
25 from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
26 
google undefined, webapp undefined

<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: cannot import name webapp
```

This is really strange to me because it's been running fine in production and on my Windows dev machine for ages, so it must be something with the platform change.  Has anyone run into this issue before?  It's like the google.appengine modules are missing or something.

Comment: Check what's in your `sys.path`. See also http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path.

Comment: I tested my path with the cmd line and got:
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
    import webob
ImportError: No module named webob

Comment: So...I'm more broken down the line, it seems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like something went wrong with your Mac GAE install mate.  I'm assuming you have Leopard installed.  As the docs say, [Leo comes with py2.5](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/devenvironment.html), I'm again assuming you are using that.  You may need to install Python 2.5 via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php) and repoint your GAE dev server to that one.  I believe that is how my MacBook is setup, but I did it so long ago I can't remember.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a dead question, but I've recently had the same problem using [django-nonrel](https://django-nonrel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/djangoappengine%20-%20Django%20App%20Engine%20backends%20%28DB,%20email,%20etc.%29.html#file-uploads-downloads), that would let me put a django project on gae.

After examining the `lib` folder from within `google_appengine`, and I've seen that I have two webob folders (`webob_1_1_1` and `webob_0_9`) so I've softlinked (`ln -s` - *nix / or simply copy) `webob_1_1_1` to `webob`.

This solved my issue.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Re the [URL shorteners-cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205806/url-shorteners-cleanup) would I be correct in saying that this URL shortener is used because of the problems with URLs which contain spaces or other unusual characters? [I'm adding this note primarily for other people involved with the clean up]